# Mysql, tipos de comentários

Tags: mysql, sintaxe

Já tinha percebido que o mysql, talvez até nem seja o único caso, mas gostaria de uma explicação em cima deste para ser mais objetivo.

Tenho vários tipos de comentários que são aceitos:

```
1) -- ESTA LINHA ESTA COMENTADA ?

2) # ESTA LINHA ESTA COMENTADA ?

3) /*ESTA LINHA ESTA COMENTATA 
   E CONTINUA COMENTADA*/

4) /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
```

Sei que posso usar tanto a opção 1 como a 2 para fazer um comentário em uma única linha e a 3 e 4 para multiplas linhas mas ainda me falta entender outros detalhes.

**Minha dúvida é/são:**

- Usar -- ou # faz alguma diferença, tem alguma recomendação de quando usar uma ou outra?
- As instruções contidas no 4) são executadas mesmo comentadas?Se sim qual o motivo de coloca-las dentro do comentário se é possível faze-las fora dele?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como o @PauloRoberto mencionou e referenciou [na resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69416/25930), os quatro tipos de comentário funcionam, mas só o comentário com `--` é ANSI SQL; outros SGBDs não aceitam os outros tipos de comentários.

Eu recomendo, portanto, que você evite usar os outros formatos de comentário pro código que você mesmo escrever: no dia que você quiser migrar pra algo mais parrudo (e você *vai* precisar migrar pra algo mais parrudo no dia que você quiser fazer algo mais complicado), você vai precisar ajeitar menos código.

---

Quanto aos comentários com `!40101`, eles são [comentários condicionais](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comments.html): eles são processados apenas por versões do MySQL maiores ou iguais ao número fornecido (no exemplo que você deu, o `SET` só vai ser executado por versões do MySQL ≥ 4.1.1); versões anteriores vão ignorar o conteúdo do comentário (e, presumo eu, bagunçar todos os caracteres acentuados na entrada contida no resto do `mysql_dump`).

Eles têm uma pegadinha importante: eles não funcionam dentro de *stored procedures*, já que o *parser* descarta comentários; se você quiser rodar comandos condicionados à versão do MySQL, você vai precisar fazer alguma coisa mais inteligente, provavelmente envolvendo SQL dinâmico.

Answer (score 1):

A documentação do MySql tem um capitulo inteiro dedicado a isso e esta em Português, tem trechos específicos e mostram como, porque e onde utilizar cada tipo de comentário.

> O servidor MySQL suporta os estilos de comentário # no fim da linha,
>   -- no fim da linha e /* na linha ou em multiplas linhas */
>
> mysql> select 1+1; # Este comentário continua até o fim da linha
>   mysql> select 1+1; -- Este comnetário continua até o fim da linha
>   mysql> select 1 /* Este é um comentário de linha */ + 1; mysql> select
>   1+ /* Este é um comentário de múltiplas linhas
>   */ 1; Note que o estilo de comentário -- requer que pelo menos um espaço após o código --!
>
> Embora o servidor entenda as sintaxes de comentários aqui descritas,
>   existem algumas limitções no modo que o cliente mysql analisa o
>   comentário /* ... */:
>
> Caracteres de aspas simples e aspas duplas são utilizados para indicar
>   o início de uma string com aspas, mesmo dentro de um comentário. Se as
>   aspas não coincidirem com uma segunda aspas dentro do comentário, o
>   analisador não percebe que o comentário tem um fim. Se você estiver
>   executando o mysql interativamente, você pode perceber a confusão
>   ocorrida por causa da mudança do prompt de mysql> para '> ou ">.
>
> Um ponto e vírgula é utilizado para indicar o fim de uma instrução SQL
>   e qualquer coisa que venha após ele indica o início da próxima
>   instrução.
>
> Estas limitações se aplicam tanto a quando se executa mysql
>   interativamente quanto quando se coloca oos comandos em um arquivo e
>   pede para que mysql leia as entradas deste arquivo com o comando mysql
>   < some-file.
>
> MySQL suporta o estilo de comentário SQL-99 '--' apenas se o segundo
>   traço for seguido de espaço Veja mais informações sobre isto na Seção
>   1.8.4.7, “'--' como Início de Comentário”.

[6.1.6. Sintaxe de Comentários](http://xoops.net.br/docs/mysql/manual/ch06.php#comments)
[1.8.4.7. '--' como Início de Comentário](http://xoops.net.br/docs/mysql/manual/ch01s08.php#ansi-diff-comments)

Comment: Eu acho que pra ganhar +1, falta mencionar que só `-- ` é ANSI SQL — os outros tipos de comentário são extensões do MySQL, e escrever código usando outros tipos de comentários vai tornar mais difícil migrar pra outro SGBD no futuro.

Comment: @ctgPi isso deve estar descrito em detalhes na documentação, por isso deixei os links ai :)

Comment: @PauloRoberto li na documentação e entendi que é recomendado usar # e não -- para que credito-!pagamento! não se torne 1--1 e virar um comentário, ok mas referente a instruções sql rodarem dentro do comentário não achei nada lá

Comment: @SneepSNinjA você não disse a linguagem que você está usando, e eu sei que é outro banco de dados, mas e.g. o psycopg2 (driver de PostgreSQL pra Python) serializa 2 como `"2"` mas -2 como `" -2"` (note o espaço); eu não ficaria surpreso se outros drivers tivessem lógica parecida pra tratar esse caso.